# Load records from database with dropdown selection without submit button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I've got two submit buttons in my form:

- Button to submit/save the form and insert the input fields to the database.
- Button to load the records into the form that are already in the database, based on a drop-down selection. For example to change the existing records in the database.

Now i know how to submit a form without clicking the submit button:

```
onChange = "this.form.submit()"
```

But what i want is to remove the 'Load button' to that if i make a selection in the drop-down it automatically loads the records, instead of submitting the total form with the code above.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: If your using jQuery, then you can submit the form by checking if the selecbox has been changed. `$('.select_boxs_class').change(function() {
  $('#forms_id').submit();
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using jquery you can load the data on a drop-down change like so:

```
$('form select').change(function() {
  alert('You should do your data loading now');
});
```

Please see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: Thanks, this is something i can use to achieve what i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Glenn Quagmire</option>
<option value="4">Joseph Swanson</option>
</select>
</form>
<br />
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the getuser.php

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'peter', 'abc123');
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ajax_demo", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '".$q."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
<th>Age</th>
<th>Hometown</th>
<th>Job</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FirstName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LastName'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Age'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Hometown'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Job'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

[Example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp) of how it works.