# Based On the dropdown list automatically increment the date from database in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My dropdown list contain options like monthly plan yearly plan etc..Then i want to select the validity starting date.When i click the starting date,based on the dropdown list  find the no of days from database and increment that value to the expiry date. How can i solve it in codeigniter.Anyone please help me.

Comment: Display your code if you can

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861679/load-records-from-database-with-dropdown-selection-without-submit-button

Answer (score 0):

Its not very clear what you want to happen but I would use the mysql DATE_ADD function to update your table with the value from your form something like

```
UPDATE `table` SET `date` = DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL $form_value DAY); //or WEEK,MONTH,YEAR
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp